# Why does the onKeyUp event return undefined in this React 18 search box?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have been working on an SPA with **React 18** and **The Movie Database (TMDB) API**.

I am currently working on a *search functionality*.

In the `Searchbox.jsx` component I have:

```
import { ReactComponent as Magnifier } from '../../icons/magnifier.svg';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Searchbox({ movie }) {

 const API_URL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';
 const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');
 const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
 const timeOutInterval = 1000;

const doMovieSearch = async (e) => {
setSearchInput(e.target.value);

if (searchInput.length >= 3) {
  const { data: { results } } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/search/movie?query=${searchInput}`, {
    params: {
      api_key: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
    }
  });

  setResults(results);
  console.log(results);
 }
}

  return (
    <form className="search_form w-100 mx-auto mt-2 mt-md-0">
      <div className="input-group">
        <input className="form-control search-box" type="text" value={searchInput} onKeyUp={debounceMovieSearch} placeholder="Search movies..." />
        <div className="input-group-append">
          <button className="btn" type="button">
            <Magnifier />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

export default Searchbox;
```

#### The problem

For a reason I have been unable to figure out, doing a search fails with this error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target').

The error is at the line `setSearchInput(e.target.value)`.

The line `console.log(results)` does not log anything.

#### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is the most reliable way to fix this issue?

Comment: You aren't passing the event to `doMovieSearch` it would need to be `const debounceMovieSearch = (event) => {setTimeout(doMovieSearch, timeOutInterval, event)}` (you can pass arguments to the callback of `setTimeout` after the delay, see: [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout))

Comment: Also `console.log(results);` right after a setState call will never log the updated state value; it won't be available until the next render cycle. see: [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: And lastly, it's not really a debounce if you never clear the previous timeout calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the event to debounceMovieSearch and pass it further to doMovieSearch:

```
import { ReactComponent as Magnifier } from '../../icons/magnifier.svg';
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Searchbox({ movie }) {

  const API_URL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const timeOutInterval = 1000;

  const doMovieSearch = async (e) => {
    setSearchInput(e.target.value);

    if (e.target.value.length >= 3) {
      const { data: { results } } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/search/movie`, {
        params: {
          api_key: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
          query: e.target.value
        }
      });

      setResults(results);
    }
  }

  const debounceMovieSearch = (e) => {
    setTimeout(() => doMovieSearch(e), timeOutInterval);
  }

return (
    <form className="search_form w-100 mx-auto mt-2 mt-md-0">
      <div className="input-group">
      <input className="form-control search-box" type="text" defaultValue={searchInput} onKeyUp={debounceMovieSearch} placeholder="Search movies..." />
        <div className="input-group-append">
          <button className="btn" type="button">
            <Magnifier />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
 );
}
export default Searchbox;
```

Additionally, I've made a small adjustment to the condition in doMovieSearch to use e.target.value.length instead of searchInput.length, as we want to check the length of the user's input, not the previous state of searchInput.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, you can use a functional update with setSearchInput to ensure that you're always using the latest value of searchInput. Here's the modified code:

```
const doMovieSearch = async (e) => {
  const inputValue = e.target.value;
  setSearchInput(inputValue);

  if (inputValue.length >= 3) {
    const { data: { results } } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/search/movie?query=${inputValue}`, {
      params: {
        api_key: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
      }
    });

    setResults(results);
    console.log(results);
  }
}

const debounceMovieSearch = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    doMovieSearch({ target: { value: searchInput } }); // Pass a mock event object with the latest searchInput value
  }, timeOutInterval);
}
```

Comment: I have made the changes. I replaced _onKeyUp_ with _onChange_ event in order to fix the error: _Warning: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler_  
 There is no error, but `console.log(results)` does not show any results.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir did you read my comment? You can't `console.log` right after a setState call. see: [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: Where should I console.log? I need to see the results...

Comment: @RazvanZamfir logging is a side effect. For that use `useEffect(() => { console.log(results), [results])`